# What is the best way to store a knowledge base of business rules for helpdesk?

Tags: knowledge-management, tool-rec

Does anyone know of any software or a good way for developers to build up a knowledge base of business rules that are built in to the software for help desk to use?

We already have a helpdesk software but we are not looking to replace this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wiki is definitely the way to go.  Processes change, sometimes frequently, and in a fast-paced environment like a help desk a tool that allows quick, easy access and management of that type of content is extremely important to allow people to do their jobs effectively.

One of the greatest benefits I've found is the heiarchical sturcture of many wikis, allowing employees to find the correct content from a number of different customer angles.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific?

This may fall under "policies and procedures" management software.  Here are some:
http://www.softscout.com/software/Human-Resources/Policy-and-Procedures.html

I'd like to find one that's more wiki-like or easier to integrate into a a website serving as a more general company knowlege base.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a wiki wiht a "Wiki Gardener" role- someone who cleans up the duplicate entries and sorts.

Wiki technology with a Rich Text Editor option would useful if your Support Desk are not totally technical.

Having some structure is imperative, developing something in any Wiki that makes sense to the general editing populace, and has a low threshold to get from reading to editing. You will also possibly need a migration strategy for taking hundereds of little notes into something more readable and searchable.